# Should I use struct tags when names of serialised fields are the same?

Tags: go

Should I declare my struct as this:

```golang
type User struct {
    FirstName   string `xml:"FirstName"`
    LastName    string `xml:"LastName"`
    PhoneNumber string `xml:"PhoneNumber"`
    Email       string `xml:"FirstName"`
    Id          string `xml:"Id"`
}
```

Or there is no need for this, as values that I would receive from XML Marshaller will be the same (in this case) with or without tags specified?

**P.S.** I know that if I need some specific behaviour, like add some value as an attribute, I should use

````
`xml:"xmlns,attr"`
``` . I'm asking only about this specific, probably the most simple case.
````

Comment: If you use them, renaming fields will not affect the serialization / deserialization format. This may or may not be what you want. You decide.

Comment: You probably want to fix the mismatch of tag name and the field name Email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go about it but there is a con here :

You will be serialising this struct to XML which usually is used in API contracts or as a payload for an external dependency. When you specify tags, you specify the payload field names and does not have dependency on your code variable names.

This keeps your payload and Go Struct decoupled and is much scalable approach to have.

Other than that, I dont think there is any performance difference as such whether you use a tag or not.

Hope this helps.